# How could I define template class member function in .cpp file? 

Tags: c++

How could I define template class member function in .cpp file?

**.h**

```
template<typename A>
class B{
 A a;
 void function();
};
```

**.cpp**

```
void B::function() 
{
}
//class used without template parameters error
```